# Trouble converting decimal value to binary

Tags: java

I'm making a program that converts decimal values to binary and vice versa. I've figured out how to convert binary to decimal, however I am having trouble with decimal to binary. I've seen many sources with code on how to do it but most of them involve using an array. I can't use an array because this program has a GUI and JLabel can't print the array. I've found a code that works with certain numbers, but doesn't with others. Here's the code:

```
public void convertBinary (int decimal)
    {
        String binary = "";
        int remainder;
        
        while (decimal != 0)
        {
            remainder = decimal % 2;
            decimal /= 2;
            binary += remainder;
        }
        lblDecBinAns.setText(String.valueOf(binary));
                
        
    }
```

The given number is inputted by the user ("decimal") which is taken when they press the button. I don't know if there's an adjustment that can be made to this code for it to work properly. Perhaps there's an entirely different algorithm that would work for this or maybe a way to print an array with JLabel. I've been stumped on this for a while so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**P.S.**
I'm aware of the .toBinary function, but I must create my own method for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it done, the only thing you are missing is to REVERSE the `binary` string

```
int decimal=10;
    String binary = "";
    int remainder;

    while (decimal != 0)
    {
        remainder = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        binary += remainder;
    }
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(binary).reverse().toString());
```

yelds

`1010` as result

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `remainder` as `binary = remainder + binary` or reverse the string. And no need to use `String.valueOf` since it's already a string. And also consider the case when `decimal` is zero you need to send `0`

```
  public String convertBinary(int decimal) {
    String binary = "";
    int remainder;
    if(decimal == 0) {
      return "0";
    }
    while (decimal != 0) {
      remainder = decimal % 2;
      decimal /= 2;
      binary = remainder + binary;
    }
    return binary;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the 0 case. I probably should've just done binary = remainder + binary; in the first place. Thought doing += would be quicker to type, not realizing that it would actually mess up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a different twist, you can also do it like this.

- Initialize the result to an empty string.
- Using the AND `&` operator, mask off the low order bit. You could also use the remainder `%` operator here too.
- Convert the bit, 1 or 0, to a string and prepend it to the result string.
- Right shift the number (`decimal`) by 1 bit so the next bit can be checked. 
  `while(!(decimal>>>1) == 0)`
- continue the while loop until `decimal == 0` (i.e. all `1` bits have been shifted out of the number).

```
public static String toBinary(int decimal) {
    // intialize the string
    String binary = Integer.toString(decimal&1);
    while ((decimal>>>=1) != 0) {
        binary  =  Integer.toString(decimal&1)+ binary;
        // or binary = Integer.toString(decimal % 2) + binary;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
String test = Integer.toString(n, 2); //n is the number to convert and 2 the base (binary). In case you want an octal number, for example, just change the base to 8.
```

But using this will cause problem in case you want to reconvert that `String` into a number just like this:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(test); //This will cause NumberFormatException.
```

To avoid the error, each char of `test` must be converted to a `char`

```
char digit = test.charAt(i);
```

Finally, convert each char to a individual `String` again

```
String converted = String.valueof(digit);
```

And now you can convert the new `String` into an `int`